# A multigang extension with rotated sockets (UK)

Tags: power

I have USB plugs with the output on the same side as the Live prong:

[image: l]

[Source](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Universal-Portable-Charger-Smartphone-Devices/dp/B00G9YK4Z2)

This means more than one plugged in next to each other in a multigang will often "bump" USB cables.

Can I buy a multigang with the sockets rotated 90°? Kinda like my diagram:

[image]

[Source](http://www.diy4u.co.uk/Category/trailing-sockets-extension-leads-surge-protection), edited with [Over](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/over-edit-photos-add-text-images-to-pictures/id535811906?mt=8)

Answer (score 2):

This is but one example of my understanding of your objective:

[Power strip Rotating Sockets UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Degree-Rotating-Intelligent-Vertical-Protection/dp/B01LKYF9A0)

[image]

It has the added benefit of providing a pair (or more) of USB outlets. I do not suggest this is the single best answer, as my search returned far more results than is possible to post here.

Using The Google with the terms "power strip rotating sockets UK" may be the best way for you to find the item to best fit your budget and requirements.

Comment: I don't think this helps - the two sockets visible on the left side would still bump usbs I think. I also have no need for it to rotate.

Comment: My post was more to present you with the suggestion to search for specific terms. This image was one of the more unconventional results. There are more linear models with rotating socket assemblies available from the suggested search.